# Can't change location to my country on newly purchased Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

I just purchased a new Xbox One at Gamestop in Norway, where the Xbox One just recently released. I explicitly requested one of the non-imported, Nordic releases of the machine.

He ensured me that's what I got.

However, during the "Getting started" part of setting up my new rig, there was no option to choose "Norway" as my Location.

Now, I can't change my location to Norway in the Settings tab either. I can however select many other countries such as the US, Australia, UAE etc. I ended up selecting United Kingdom, but as they've got some wicked postal codes, the Norwegians ones won't even validate when e.g. adding a credit card.

Might it be that I just got an imported Xbox?

Comment: have you updated the system? I have Norway in my settings selection. I'll answer with steps I took.

Comment: Yeah. I asked me to update as soon as I booted it up for the first time. After that I was forced to select a location, at which Norway was not even available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

If you update your console to the "Windows 10" release, you can select your location, language, and region language freely. Navigate to Settings->Language and region to do so

**old stuff for people who did not update**

In order to change your location you must go in order.

You must first make sure the system is up to date (your area may not be on the initial set up, this is fine... you can change regions freely, just pick whatever you can understand).

Go to System settings

Language and Location

Select the Region's native language (Norsk in your case), Language *must* be chosen first

All further fields will update accordingly, change them as you need.

Comment: That was it. You actually have to change your language before "Norge" even becomes an option as your location. Kind of stupid if you ask me, as many many gamers really dislike anything but English on their computers and console. Guess I will be switching to Norwegian when adding credit cards or purchasing stuff, then back to United Kingdom when just playing and having fun. Thanks.

Comment: I also noticed that while my location is now correct, it is impossible to select English as your system language. So I guess your out of luck if you are English-speaking, and recently moved to Norway. I would not mind if it was just the menu, but this also affect in-game content. In Watch_Dogs, I can hardly understand any of the written dialogue and other text. Nice work, Microsoft!

Comment: Mircosoft unfortunately always had a console to disrespect user language choice on their Live platform. They assume they know what language you speak based on your country and will give you one, maybe two options. Together with the lacking support for smaller countries (or should I say markets) this leads to a diminished user experience, especially if you move to a different country. The solution is migration to a country where you can select the language of choice. Unfortunately your credit card will stop working. An well...